# How can I map a query result to domain objects?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm developping a program that uses the neo4j-ogm library directly (aka I don't use any Spring component) and my Neo4J DB has this sorts of relations:

`PARAMETER<-[:HAS_PARAMETER]-TASK-[:HAS_STEP]->STEP-[:HAS_PARAMETER]->PARAMETER
STEP-[:HAS_STEP]->STEP
PARAMETER-[:INITIALIZES]->PARAMETER`

I coded all my domain classes (PARAMETER, TASK and STEP).

I write a query like (with a `session.query` method call):
`MATCH (:TASK)-[r*]->() return r`

Can I directly map the result from my query to domain objects?

EDIT:
To be sharper, I've got this class Task

```
@NodeEntity
    class Task {
        @RelationShip(type = "HAS_STEP")
        Set<Step> steps;

        @RelationShip(type = "HAS_PARAMETER")  
        Set<Parameter> parameters;
    }
```

I wish fill a Task instance (with steps and parameters) and each step be filled too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `session.query()` to return a `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result` that contains the results. This is supported only in Neo4j OGM 2.0.1.

Returning a path is not supported, so you must return the nodes and relationships that comprise the path e.g.

`MATCH p=(t:TASK)-[r*]->() return t, nodes(p), rels(p)`

Then, you can access `t` from the `Result` and it will be a hydrated Task. Alternatively, you can access the nodes from the `Result` for all hydrated entities in the path.

More examples are in the test here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/session/capability/QueryCapabilityTest.java

BTW the blog post that Christophe references is still valid for the OGM functionality as well if you need to understand what can be mapped.

Comment: It works for getting an object :) But, how can I mix object and calculated value in my query ? I read the document of Christophe but the annotations @Query and QueryResult don't seem implemented in the neo4j-ogm.

Comment: Just return objects and calculated values- your Result will contain values for each. The entities will be mapped to domain objects and the calculated values will be available as is. See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/session/capability/QueryCapabilityTest.java#L260

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, there is a complete blog post about it :

http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html

Comment: It seems specific to Spring Data framework :( Is there a solution with the neo4j-ogm library ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the sentence part "SDN and Neo4J-OGM". That should mean the solution works either with SDN or Neo4J-OGM.